# Chart.js showing old data on hover

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm using chart.js for my laravel project.
I have one chart & 3 buttons

when user clicks on button 0 with id ='0'

i will update the data & lables of the current chart using this code

My Code

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartBig1").getContext('2d');

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.1)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(119,52,169,0)'); //purple colors

    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: @json($userDataMonth['labels']),
            datasets: [{
                label: "Users",
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
                borderColor: '#d346b1',
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                pointBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
                pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
                pointBorderWidth: 20,
                pointHoverRadius: 4,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
                pointRadius: 4,
                data: @json($userDataMonth['data']),
            }]
        },
        options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
    };
    var myChartData = new Chart(ctx, config);

    $("#0").click(function() {
        var data = myChartData.config.data;
        data.datasets[0].data = @json($userDataMonth['data']);
        data.labels = @json($userDataMonth['labels']);
        myChartData.update();
    });

    $("#1").click(function() {
        var data = myChartData.config.data;
        data.datasets[0].data = @json($userDataWeek['data']);
        data.labels = @json($userDataWeek['labels']);
        myChartData.update();
    });

    $("#2").click(function() {
        var data = myChartData.config.data;
        data.datasets[0].data = @json($userDataDay['data']);
        data.labels = @json($userDataDay['labels']);
        myChartData.update();
    });
```

The issue is the chart shows old data when i hover over it (view below gif for more clearity)

[image]